# Activating an imported module - Python version mismatch

Tags: add-on, customization

I don't have experience with addons but it should work when I download the .zip from github and install it over the preference window. I want to keep using Blender 2.8 for modelling but the error states that I get when trying to active the module:

> There is a Python version mismatch.

The module is called Animation Nodes and is compiled for Python ver. 3.5.3 yet Blender 2.8 uses Python ver. 3.7.0. What can I do to use it because Blender 2.79 doesn't work with the addon if I remember correctly. Also I want to keep working with 2.8.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you need to wait until someone upgrade it.**

Since Blender 2.8 change *a lot of* code APIs (and Python to 3.7.0), it is currently not possible to use the add-on directly if the code is not upgrade to 2.8 APIs.

It might be possible to upgrade the script by your self, but for those complicated scripts like *Animation Node*, there will be a lot of thing need to fix.

Here is a discussion: [Updating Built In Addons to Blender 2.8](https://blenderartists.org/t/updating-built-in-addons-to-blender-2-8/1148566), and some one even maintain an APIs change list under the discussion.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I noticed that he specially compiled the addon for 2.8 in a different repository. Otherwise updating it manually myself would have been the only other option. Thanks again, this issue has been resolved.